# How to merge two tables together, choosing the column with the higher value, without being able to use MERGE statement?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two simple tables:

**source**

```
id    count  date
6       30  10-28
7       80  10-29
5       20  10-28
4       10  10-27
```

**destination**

```
id    count  date   
7       10  10-29
5       90  10-28
6       10  10-28
```

What I want is to merge the contents of the source into a destination, where their ids and dates match and the maximum value of count is compared and chosen. The query should also be able to insert a row from the source into destination if a row with that id+date doesn't already exist in destination.

After running the query, **destination** should look like:

```
id    count  date   
7       80  10-29
5       90  10-28
6       30  10-28
4       10  10-27
```

This is the query I've thought of so far, but I'm having trouble actually updating the destination table, and I'm not able to use MERGE. I'm also not sure of its efficiency:

```
select id, max(count), date from (
   select id, max(count) as count, date from source group by id, count, date
   union
   select id, max(count) as count, date from destination group by id, count, date
)
group by id, date;
```

I'm using Amazon Redshift to run my queries.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greatest` might be used with `left join` as :

```
select s.id, greatest(s.count,d.count) as count, 
       s.date
  from source s
  left join destination d 
    on ( s.id = d.id and s.date = d.date );
```

*P.S. if a value in the list inside the `greatest`(or `least` for cases for minimum values) evaluate to `NULL`, then it's ignored.*

If you just don't want to select but to change the destination table without a merge statement, you may use a *CTAS*(*create table as*) statement as in the following block :

```
create table destination2 as 
select s.id, greatest(s.count,d.count) as count, s.date
  from source s
  left join destination d 
    on ( s.id = d.id and s.date = d.date );

delete from destination;

insert into destination
select * from destination2;

drop table destination2;

select * from destination;
```

Comment: Why `greatest` when `coalesce` returns a single column? `greatest(10)`?

Comment: @dnoeth while I was away from my computer, realised that I missed the point related to `coalesce`, and thought that somebody would warn me :) thanks, you're right exactly.

Comment: I don't know how Redshift implements `greatest`, but in Teradata & Oracle (but not PostgreSQL) it's returning NULL if any of the operands is NULL (I hate that). You might need two `coalesce` or at least one for `d.count` :-)

Comment: Does this update the destination table with the new values?

Comment: @dnoeth as you mentioned the issue with nulls in Oracle, my primary DB for knowledge , confused me.  Met through research that's not a problem for Postgresql and Amazon-Redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Of course MERGE is just a (more efficient) replacement for a wellknown two-step process:

```
-- first update existing id/date combinations
update dest
set count = src.count
from source
where dest.id    = src.id
  and dest.date  = src.date
  and dest.count < src.count;

-- then insert new id/date combinations
insert into dest
select id, count, date
from src
where not exists
 ( select * from dest
   where dest.id    = src.id
     and dest.date  = src.date
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the table using `union all` or `full join`:

```
select id, date, max(count) as count
from ((select id, date, count from source
      ) union all
      (select id, date, count from destination
      )
     ) t
group by id, date;
```

If you want to save these results in a table, I would be inclined to recommend creating a new table and replacing the old:

```
create table new_destination as
    select id, date, max(count) as count
    from ((select id, date, count from source
          ) union all
          (select id, date, count from destination
          )
         ) t
    group by id, date;

truncate table destination;

insert into destination (id, date, count)
    select id, date, count
    from destination;
```